# Treat using NSLog as a build error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, nslog

I want to treat any `NSLog` in my code as an error. The line should be a compile time error in Xcode. Just like how usage of `release` in an ARC enabled project is treated as an error.

Comment: Then how "release" is shown as error in ARC enabled project?

Comment: You can simply search all `NSLog (command+shift+F)` and replace it with `//NSLog` before debugging.

Comment: Yes, "Search and replace" is a Simple solution, but still people who join new in team, may still use NSLog, forgetting to replace NSLog sometimes, So checking possibility to prevent it ultimately by marking as compile time error.

Comment: @VinothKumar I edited your question for clarity and tags to help get the best answers apologies if I misrepresented anything

Comment: @CarlVeazey, Thanks for the editing. It is more clear now.

Comment: Just now found when I deliberately use [foo release] in arc enabled project, in this case also the two errors namely Apple Mach-O error and DSymbutil error are appearing. So accepting the answers of iMartin, dreamlax and Bhargavi. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
#define NSLog_UNAVAILABLE __attribute__((unavailable("NSLog is treated as Error.")))
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) NSLog_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Comment: @VinothKumar Is that what you need ?

Comment: Thanks iMartin, dreamlax, bhargavi.

Comment: I'd suggest doing that only for release builds.  Thus you can use nslog for debug purposes (hey, it happens) and it'll fail mightily for release builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can redeclare prototype of `NSLog` in your code with `__deprecated`, so any use of it will produce **warning**:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) __deprecated;
```

Then maybe there is some way to turn warnign into error.

Comment: This gives warning wherever NSLog used. Thanks, will check any ways to show warning as error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you use Clang as your compiler (actually just realised GCC also supports C11's `_Static_assert` too from version 4.6):

```
#define NSLog(...) _Static_assert(0, "Not allowed to use NSLog!")
```

Compilation will fail if a `_Static_assert` fails.

Comment: NSlog shown as error in Xcode 4.6, however 2 more errors are also getting added new, namely Apple Mach-O linker error and Symutil Error.

Comment: FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) __unavailable; This also works as iMartin suggested, however 2 more errors are getting added up, namely Apple Mach-O error and DSymbutil error

Comment: @VinothKumar: I don't know what you mean, I tried it and it works, so maybe your error is elsewhere? Make sure you spell everything in the correct case.